# Designing a Page de Couverture

Tags: exam

I was wondering how it was possible in LaTeX to do such a [image: thing]

I know how to rotate the writing, but how can I write this close to the upper margin and still have such a design ?

Comment: Have you had a look at coffins? It seems to be one of the applications for them (see package xcoffins).

Comment: May I observe this couldn't in any case be a ‘page de garde’ – it denotes a *blank* page at the beginning and at the end of a book. So a ‘page de garde’ requires no formatting.